# Which is correct - has come vs has came

Tags: tense, present-perfect, auxiliary-verbs

1. The file has not **come yet**.
2. The file has not **came yet**.
3. The file has not **came**.

Comment: Welcome to Ell. Would you tell us what you think yourself? You can edit your post and add your view.

Comment: Only #1is correct.

Comment: @user178049:  Would you care to explain why, so that the OP and other users can learn something?

Comment: How to form the present perfect tense is really very basic grammar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only the first one is correct because the basic form of perfect tense is have/has/had + past participle.

Come is a confusing word in English because its plain form and its past participle form are the same.

Plain form : *come*

Present participle : *coming*

Past participle : *come*

Past tense : *came*

Answer (score 0):

The sentence #1 is grammatical.

The auxiliary verbs has and have are used with the past particple (the third form) of a verb to form a sentence in the present perfect.  The three forms of the verb come are come, came, and come.

So only the first sentence with the past participle "come" is OK.

Comment: No. "Come" is the PAST participle, which is why it is used here. Unusually it is the same as the present tense, and different to the simple past. The PRESENT participle is "coming". "They are coming soon".

Comment: @WS2,   I know the past participle of come is come.  I am sorry, it was a typo.